# Shopify if NOT homepage?

Tags: shopify, liquid

How do I detect shopify `if Homepage`? Previously there was a handler which was `page.frontpage` which is not used anymore.

I need to exclude something from the homepage, so I can't go for editing the `index.liquid` file.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is how we can do that:

```
{% if template.name != "index" %} 
 do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This checks if it's NOT the homepage. See @brenthack35's answer for a working solution.

Answer (score 7):

To detect the homepage you should use double equals "==" the use of the exclamation "!=" is finding everything "not" equal to "index".

```
{% if template.name == "index" %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use it in this way:

```
    {% if template.name != "index" %}
      do something
    {% endif %}
```